# write data to file within vendor directory

Tags: php, json, github, composer-php

I have developed a php class which would be hosted on github and packagist. I have a created a `data.json` file to read/write credentials data.

```
$data = array(
    'access_token' => $access_token
);
$data = json_encode($data);

if(is_writable('data.json')) file_put_contents('data.json', $data);
```

When i install this package in my other app using `composer`, i get following error...

```
file_get_contents(data.json) failed to open stream: No Such file or directory.
```

I really want to save access_token to data.json which will be in vendor directory, so suggest me any good way to achieve this. Thanks

Comment: You post `file_put_contents('data.json' ...`, not `file_get_contents('data.json')`. BTW, you should use always absolute path

Comment: @Leggendario what should be absolute path in case of vendor directory or composer package.

Comment: I don't understand where is "data.json". In the vendor dir?

Comment: @Leggendario Its in my namespace `/user/test/testClass` or `/vendor/user/test/`